# Ошибка в коде 1с

Tags: 1с

Пишем код для расчета себестоимости товара в 1С. Код документа "Реализация товаров и услуг" приложу ниже. Код работает, но преподаватель говорит, что в нем есть алгоритмический недочет, который может привести к критической ошибке.
Помогите его найти, пожалуйста, если разбираетесь. Я не могу найти :(

[image: Пример нашей разработки, на которой видны созданные документы]

```
Процедура ОбработкаЗаполнения(ДанныеЗаполнения, СтандартнаяОбработка)
//{{__КОНСТРУКТОР_ВВОД_НА_ОСНОВАНИИ
// Данный фрагмент построен конструктором.
// При повторном использовании конструктора, внесенные вручную изменения будут утеряны!!!
Если ТипЗнч(ДанныеЗаполнения) = Тип("ДокументСсылка.ЗаказКлиента") Тогда
    // Заполнение шапки
    ИтогСУчетомСкидки = ДанныеЗаполнения.ИтогСУчетомСкидки;
    Клиент = ДанныеЗаполнения.Клиент;
    СуммаДокумента = ДанныеЗаполнения.СуммаДокумента;
    Для Каждого ТекСтрокаТовары Из ДанныеЗаполнения.Товары Цикл
        НоваяСтрока = Товары.Добавить();
        НоваяСтрока.Количество = ТекСтрокаТовары.Количество;
        НоваяСтрока.Сумма = ТекСтрокаТовары.Сумма;
        НоваяСтрока.Товар = ТекСтрокаТовары.Товар;
        НоваяСтрока.Цена = ТекСтрокаТовары.Цена;
    КонецЦикла;
КонецЕсли;
//}}__КОНСТРУКТОР_ВВОД_НА_ОСНОВАНИИ
```

КонецПроцедуры

Процедура ОбработкаПроведения(Отказ, Режим)

```
// регистр Взаиморасчеты Приход
Движения.Взаиморасчеты.Записывать = Истина;
Для Каждого ТекСтрокаТовары Из Товары Цикл
    Движение = Движения.Взаиморасчеты.Добавить();
    Движение.ВидДвижения = ВидДвиженияНакопления.Приход;
    Движение.Период = Дата;
    Движение.Контрагенты = Клиент;
    Движение.Сумма = ИтогСУчетомСкидки;
КонецЦикла;

// регистр Продажи Приход
Движения.Продажи.Записывать = Истина;
Для Каждого ТекСтрокаТовары Из Товары Цикл
    Движение = Движения.Продажи.Добавить();
    //Движение.ВидДвижения = ВидДвиженияНакопления.Приход;
    Движение.Период = Дата;
    Движение.Клиент = Клиент;
    Движение.Номенклатура = ТекСтрокаТовары.Товар;
    Движение.Количество = ТекСтрокаТовары.Количество;
    Движение.Сумма = ТекСтрокаТовары.Сумма;
//КонецЦикла;
// регистр ТоварыНаСкладах Расход
Движения.ТоварыНаСкладах.Записывать = Истина;
//Для Каждого ТекСтрокаТовары Из Товары Цикл
    Движение = Движения.ТоварыНаСкладах.Добавить();
    Движение.ВидДвижения = ВидДвиженияНакопления.Расход;
    Движение.Период = Дата;
    Движение.Номенклатура = ТекСтрокаТовары.Товар;
    Движение.Склад = Склад;
    Движение.Количество = ТекСтрокаТовары.Количество;
КонецЦикла;   

Движения.Записать();
Если Режим=РежимПроведенияДокумента.Оперативный Тогда

        //{{КОНСТРУКТОР_ЗАПРОСА_С_ОБРАБОТКОЙ_РЕЗУЛЬТАТА
// Данный фрагмент построен конструктором.
// При повторном использовании конструктора, внесенные вручную изменения будут утеряны!!!

Запрос = Новый Запрос;
Запрос.Текст = 
    "ВЫБРАТЬ
    |   ТоварыНаСкладахОстатки.Номенклатура КАК Номенклатура,
    |   ТоварыНаСкладахОстатки.Склад КАК Склад,
    |   -ТоварыНаСкладахОстатки.КоличествоОстаток КАК КоличествоОстаток
    |ИЗ
    |   РегистрНакопления.ТоварыНаСкладах.Остатки(
    |           ,
    |           Склад = &Склад
    |               И Номенклатура В
    |                   (ВЫБРАТЬ
    |                       РеализацияТоваровИУслугТовары.Товар КАК Товар
    |                   ИЗ
    |                       Документ.РеализацияТоваровИУслуг.Товары КАК РеализацияТоваровИУслугТовары
    |                   ГДЕ
    |                       РеализацияТоваровИУслугТовары.Ссылка = &Ссылка)) КАК ТоварыНаСкладахОстатки
    |ГДЕ
    |   ТоварыНаСкладахОстатки.КоличествоОстаток < 0";

Запрос.УстановитьПараметр("Склад", Склад);
Запрос.УстановитьПараметр("Ссылка", Ссылка);

РезультатЗапроса = Запрос.Выполнить();
Если РезультатЗапроса.Пустой()Тогда  
    Сообщить("Реализация товара успешно произведена!");
ИНАЧЕ   
    ВыборкаДетальныеЗаписи = РезультатЗапроса.Выбрать();
    Пока ВыборкаДетальныеЗаписи.Следующий() Цикл     
    Отказ=Истина;
    Сообщить("Недостаточно товара! "+ ВыборкаДетальныеЗаписи.Номенклатура +" в количестве " + ВыборкаДетальныеЗаписи.КоличествоОстаток);    
    КонецЦикла;
КонецЕсли; 

КонецЕсли;

//Движения для Себестоимости товаров!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!11
Если НЕ Отказ Тогда
      Движения.СебестоимостьТоваров.Записывать = Истина;
      // регистр Продажи
      Движения.Продажи.Записывать = Истина;
    
Запрос = Новый Запрос;
Запрос.Текст = 
    "ВЫБРАТЬ
    |   СебестоимостьТоваровОстатки.Номенклатура КАК Номенклатура,
    |   СебестоимостьТоваровОстатки.СуммаОстаток КАК Сумма,
    |   ЕСТЬNULL(СебестоимостьТоваровОстатки.КоличествоОстаток,0) КАК Количество
    |ИЗ
    |   РегистрНакопления.СебестоимостьТоваров.Остатки (
    |        &МоментВремени,
    |        Номенклатура В
    |           (ВЫБРАТЬ
    |               РеализацияТоваровИУслугТовары.Товар
    |            ИЗ
    |               Документ.РеализацияТоваровИУслуг.Товары КАК РеализацияТоваровИУслугТовары
    |            ГДЕ
    |               РеализацияТоваровИУслугТовары.Ссылка = &Ссылка)) КАК  СебестоимостьТоваровОстатки";
    
Запрос.УстановитьПараметр("МоментВремени", МоментВремени());
Запрос.УстановитьПараметр("Ссылка", Ссылка);        
РезультатЗапроса = Запрос.Выполнить();
ВыборкаДетальныеЗаписи = РезультатЗапроса.Выбрать();

Пока ВыборкаДетальныеЗаписи.Следующий() Цикл
    СебестоимостьЕдиницы=ВыборкаДетальныеЗаписи.Сумма/ВыборкаДетальныеЗаписи.Количество;
    Движение = Движения.СебестоимостьТоваров.Добавить();
    Движение.ВидДвижения = ВидДвиженияНакопления.Расход;
    Движение.Период = Дата;
    Движение.Номенклатура = ВыборкаДетальныеЗаписи.Номенклатура;
    ТекСтр=Товары.Найти(ВыборкаДетальныеЗаписи.Номенклатура, "Товар"); 
    Движение.Количество = ТекСтр.Количество;
    Движение.Сумма = СебестоимостьЕдиницы*ТекСтр.Количество; 
    
    Движение = Движения.Продажи.Добавить();
    Движение.Период = Дата;
    Движение.Клиент = Клиент;
    Движение.Номенклатура = ВыборкаДетальныеЗаписи.Номенклатура;
    Движение.Количество = ТекСтр.Количество;
    Движение.Сумма = ТекСтр.Сумма;     
    Движение.Себестоимость = СебестоимостьЕдиницы*ТекСтр.Количество

//КонецЦикла;  

// регистр Продажи
//Движения.Продажи.Записывать = Истина;
//Для каждого ТекСтрокаТовары Из Товары Цикл
        КонецЦикла;
```

КонецЕсли;
КонецПроцедуры

Answer (score 0):

Для начала я бы рекомендовал: вначале проверить Остатки - и только потом делать движения по другим регистрам;

Кроме этого : было бы неплохо свернуть табличную часть, все движения делать на свернутом результате; Желательно использовать режим блокировок = Управляемый на всех регистрах, и добавить код блокировки; (см. пример)

```
// Списание по партиям
    Блокировка = Новый БлокировкаДанных;
    ЭлБлокировки = Блокировка.Добавить("РегистрНакопления.Себестоимость");
    ЭлБлокировки.Режим = РежимБлокировкиДанных.Исключительный;
    
    ЗапросН = Новый Запрос;
    ЗапросН.МенеджерВременныхТаблиц = Запрос.МенеджерВременныхТаблиц;    
    ЗапросН.Текст = 
    "ВЫБРАТЬ
    |   ДокТЧ.Номенклатура КАК Номенклатура    
    |ИЗ
    |   ДокТЧ КАК ДокТЧ";
    РезультатНоменклатура = ЗапросН.Выполнить();    
    ЭлБлокировки.ИсточникДанных = РезультатНоменклатура;
    ЭлБлокировки.ИспользоватьИзИсточникаДанных("Номенклатура", "Номенклатура");
    Блокировка.Заблокировать();
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! Буду думать